# Isolated scope on template appended to element parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive("mydirective", ['$compile', function($compile) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
        var actionBtnHTML = `<button type="submit" ng-show="show"></button>`;

        element.parent().append(actionBtnHTML);

        $compile(element)(scope);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: link,
        controller: ['$scope', function MyDirectiveController($scope) {
            $scope.show = true;
        }]
}]);
```

My directive simply adds a button after the HTML tag with the `mydirective` attribute.

I want that the added HTML has the same scope as the directive (ie. the new isolated scope). But it is not the case in this configuration. I guess this is because the added HTML is outside the directive HTML tag.

Whence my question, how can I apply the isolated scope of my directive on the template appended to parent element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ngTransclude`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) to insert the extra HTML content while keeping the same scope of the directive.

```
directive("mydirective", ['$compile', function($compile) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    controller: ['$scope', function MyDirectiveController($scope) {
      $scope.show = true;
    }],
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
      ' <button type="submit" ng-show="show">Submit!</button>'
  }
}])
```

Here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzoxLLsw/) for your directive!

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It works well but it forces me to wrap the original HTML tag into a div with the directive attribute. Not really important but I would like a less intrusive directive. Actually, I manage to solve my problem by applying the `$compile()` method on `element.parent()` instead of `element`. I don't know if it is the right way to do it but it seems to work.